# How can I perform this non circular shift in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, shift

I am trying to perform a non circular shift in MATLAB. I have

`A = [1 2 3 4 5; 0 0 13 14 15; 21 22 23 24 25; 0 0 33 34 35 ; 41 42 43 44 45`]

and

`B = [1 2 3 4 5; 11 12 13 14 15; 21 22 23 24 25; 31 32 33 34 35 ; 41 42 43 44 45`]

How can I shift the indexes of the even rows and is it possible to fill in the empty indexes with an integer of choice?

Desired outputs:

```
 A = 
     1     2    3      4      5  
     13    14   15           
     21    22   23     24     25
     33    34   35           
     41    42   43     44     45

B = 
         1     2    3     4     5  
                    11    12    13    14    15           
         21    22   23    24    25
                    31    32    33    34    35      
         41    42   43    44    45
```

Edit: Realized I messed up the desired output of matrix B. I had accidentally omitted some of the elements. Trying to shift the variables over to the right non circularly

Comment: For the expected output for matrix `B` what is the behaviour of the 3rd row it doesn't seem to follow the trends of the other shifts?

Comment: that is a beautifull desired output, but it makes no sense computer-memory wise. Not even the input, if you are using matrices!

Comment: Im sorry I missed some integers. The aim is to shift the even rows of matrix B two over to the right. I fixed the output and added details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using Indexing and Concatenation

**Input Arrays:**

```
A = [1  2  3  4  5; 
     0  0  13 14 15; 
     21 22 23 24 25;
     0  0  33 34 35 ; 
     41 42 43 44 45];


B = [1  2  3  4  5; 
     11 12 13 14 15; 
     21 22 23 24 25; 
     31 32 33 34 35;
     41 42 43 44 45];
```

---

### Shifting Even Rows Left:

To shift the arrays you can index the arrays relative to the `Shift_Factor` in this case 2. You can alternatively use `circshift()` and overwrite the portions of the array with zeroes/the desired `Fill_Value`. Here a for loop with an increment value of 2 is used to iterate over all the even rows. Upon each iteration, a partition of the array `A(Row,Shift_Factor+1:end)` is concatenated to an arbitrary fill array `Fill_Value*ones(1,Shift_Factor)`.

```
Shift_Factor = 2;
Fill_Value = 0;

[Number_Of_Rows,Number_Of_Columns] = size(A);

for Row = 2: +2: Number_Of_Rows
    A(Row,:) = [A(Row,Shift_Factor+1:end) Fill_Value*ones(1,Shift_Factor)];
end

A
```

[image: Result of Shifting Matrix A Left]

---

### Shifting Even Rows Right

```
Shift_Factor = 2;
Fill_Value = 0;

[Number_Of_Rows,Number_Of_Columns] = size(B);
B = [B zeros(Number_Of_Rows,Shift_Factor)];

for Row = 2: +2: Number_Of_Rows
    B(Row,:) = [Fill_Value*ones(1,Shift_Factor) B(Row,1:end-Shift_Factor)];
end


B
```

[image: Result of Shifting Matrix B Right]

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: Sorry I had edited the B array because I was missing some values. Is this more clear?

Comment: No worries, yeah though it was a small typo. I editing my accordingly answer now.